# What is the best/most efficient way to store User Sensative Data in MySQL

Tags: php, python, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

What would be the best way to save user sensational data like documents that people have typed? Would it be easiest to make a database of a bunch of VARCHAR(8000) rows, or should I make independent protected files? I don't want opinions, just facts. Thanks!

Comment: This is too vague to answer objectively in its current form. Do the documents have to be in a database? What and whom will be accessing the files? Etc. etc.

Comment: You get facts in exchange for other facts.

Comment: Thats my point, should I store file info in a db, or as encrypted files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encrypt it :). Someone already asked this, so check this out:

[What's the best way to store sensitive data in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797692/whats-the-best-way-to-store-sensitive-data-in-mysql)

Comment: But than I need to decrypt it to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

Storing an encrypted file on the system and then storing that filename only in the database will allow you to easily leverage command line encryption tools like pgp in order to use strong encryption on the file content.